# Array of settings values are recommended to keep inside a .net core Appsettings file

Tags: c#, .net-core, appsettings

I am building a console app and i have to save a couple of settings values and some of them is an array of values A sample section of Appsettings i am thinking is like below

```
    "FolderSettings":{
            "source": "c:\\sourcefolder",
            "target": "c:\\targetfolder"
    },
    "FolderJPG":[
        {
        "name":"foldername",
        "width":1450,
        "height":1450
        }
    ],
    "FolderPNG":[
        {
        "name":"foldername",
        "width":300,
        "height":300
        },
        {
        "name":"foldername2",
        "width":450,
        "height":450
        }
    ]
```

Is it recommended to save the array of settings values in appsettings file  [ FolderJPG and FolderPNG in this case ] or is there any recommended ways to keep such settings in .net core?

Also, how can i fetch the settings values as an array of values? I know the way to read a simple  key-value pair will be like

```
    _configuration.GetValue<string>("FolderSettings:source");
```

But how can I read the array of settings values for FolderJPG, FolderPNG etc correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind it to the model

```
public class FolderOption
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Width{ get; set; }
   public int Height{ get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
_configuration.GetSection("FolderJPG").Get<List<FolderOption>>();
```

The *appsettings.json* can contain any configuration that you need with restriction - it should be JSON.

> JSON objects are written in key/value pairs.
>
> Keys must be strings, and
> values must be a valid JSON data type (string, number, object, array,
> boolean or null).

So, an array is just data type of value

Comment: Is it recommended to keep an Array of settings inside app settings file? Since i read in some blogs appsettings is for a key value pair settings mostly

Comment: Yes, appsettings.json can contain any configuration that you need with one restriction - it should be json.